# Operator Precedence with Ternary Conditional and Logical And operators in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, operator-precedence

Hey guys i was just going through the source of a JS plugin ([dropdown.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/dropdown.js#L123)) and came across the following line of code:

```
return $parent && $parent.length ? $parent : $this.parent()
```

I am not able to grasp the above line completely, I understand Logical And (&&) and the Ternary Conditional Operator (`... ? ... : ...`), but I don't seem to comprehend how they interact in the above example.

Now if I add a `console.log` before the `return` statement:

```
console.log($parent && $parent.length ? $parent : $this.parent());
```

I get:

```
Object { 0: <li.dropdown.open>, length: 1, prevObject: Object, context: <a.dropdown-toggle>, selector: ".parent()" }
```

Which indeed is `$this.parent()`

Also, `$parent` in my case evaluates to `false`.

So these are the Lego pieces I have, can somebody put it in place for me and give me a clear picture of how this works:

```
return $parent && $parent.length ? $parent : $this.parent()
```

Thank you.

---

**Please note that the pre-edit version of this question had an incorrect title and didn't explain what the question really was until one looked at it with sufficient care, therefore please don't downvote any answers below that may seem to talk about "Short-circuiting" in place of the actual topic of this question (Operator Precedence) for the sole sake of looking out-of-topic and careless*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to JavaScript's [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), the expression you posted is equivalent to:

```
return ($parent && $parent.length) ? $parent : $this.parent();
```

This is due to the `&&` operator being evaluated before `?:`. Alternatively, you can rewrite the expression using `if else`:

```
if ($parent && $parent.length)
    return $parent;
else
    return $this.parent();
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, especially within conditional statements,the following is true

```
if($parent) //checking whether the $parent variable has a value
```

The conditional statement you've posted is something of the following sort in words

If $parent is not null/undefined and $parent.length is not null/undefined, then return $parent, else return $this.parent();

Let's look at that statement again

```
return $parent && $parent.length ? $parent : $this.parent();
```

The first is the condition for the ternary operator

```
$parent && $parent.length
```

The short-circuit operator here works, because if $parent is null/undefined, it will not evaluate $parent.length (which will throw a javascript exception). If it is not null, it evaluates if $parent.length is not null/undefined.

The same code can be written as (using 'null' only for brevity)

```
if($parent != null && $parent.length !=null) {
    return $parent;
} else {
    return $this.parent();
}
```

Comment: the way i look at `if($parent)` is "check if $parent is truthy or falsy" .

Comment: Thanks  @Serendipity - for the detailed explanation and for your time to do that - I am now able to understand how it works!

Answer (score 1):

Here, both `$parent` and `$this` are JQuery objects. The line `$parent && $parent.length ? $parent : $this.parent()` is equivalent to:

```
if($parent && $parent.length) {
  return $parent;
}
return $this.parent();
```

So `$parent && $parent.length` is actually evaluated as: *if `$parent` and `$parent.length` are not `null`, `undefined`, `0` or `false` (falsy values), then return `$parent`, else return `$this.parent()`.*

Answer (score 0):

```
return ($parent && $parent.length) ? $parent : $this.parent()
```

read it like that. both conditions need to be true. In JS, an && operand will return false as soon as a condition is false

Answer (score 0):

If `$parent` resolves to a "truthy" value, and so does `$parent.length` (which means in this case that it isn't 0), then it will return the value of `$parent`.

If `$parent` is false (so most likely null or undefined), or the length of parent is 0, then it returns `$this.parent()`.